# Pacman repaint issue

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, interface, paint

im making a pacman with movement by rounds and a given final position. I already have the game working in cmd, with the ghost logics, the score/points, etc. Now i want to show that in a GUI, but im having some issues.

This is the VIEW

```
package vista;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import controlador.Controlador;

public class Vista extends JFrame {

    Tablero t;
    JFrame frame;

    public Vista(Controlador c) {
        frame = new JFrame();
        t = new Tablero(c);
        frame.add(t);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(600, 600);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actualizar() {
        t.repaint();
    }

}
```

This is the "board"

```
package vista;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import controlador.Controlador;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.GridLayout;

public class Tablero extends JPanel {

    JPanel[][] panelHolder = new JPanel[31][28];
    ImageIcon pacman = new ImageIcon("imagenes/pacman_der_abierto.gif");
    ImageIcon pared = new ImageIcon("imagenes/wall.gif");
    ImageIcon pellet = new ImageIcon("imagenes/pacdot.gif");
    ImageIcon powerPellet = new ImageIcon("imagenes/powerpellet.gif");
    ImageIcon vacio = new ImageIcon("imagenes/black.gif");
    Controlador c;

    public Tablero(Controlador con){
        c=con;    
        this.setLayout(new GridLayout(31,28));
            for(int y=0; y<31; y++)
                for(int x=0; x<28; x++){
                    panelHolder[y][x]=new JPanel();
                    panelHolder[y][x].setSize(230, 230);
                    this.add(panelHolder[y][x]);
                }
            this.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        int dataMap[][] = c.getDataMap();
        System.out.println("Actual : "+dataMap[y][x]); //Test, its working!
        for(int y=0; y<31; y++)
            for(int x=0; x<28; x++){
                //System.out.println("Actual : "+dataMap[y][x]);
                JLabel a = new JLabel();
                switch(dataMap[y][x]){
                case -1:
                    a.setIcon(pared);
                    panelHolder[y][x].add(a);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    a.setIcon(pellet);
                    panelHolder[y][x].add(a);
                    break;
                case 50:
                    a.setIcon(powerPellet);
                    panelHolder[y][x].add(a);
                    break;
                case 0:
                    a.setIcon(vacio);
                    panelHolder[y][x].add(a);
                    break;
                }

            }
    }

}
```

This are the CONTROLLER classes, one of them (Pacman) is the main class

```
package controlador;

import java.util.Scanner;

import modelo.personajes.Jugador;
import vista.Vista;

public class Pacman {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Jugador pacman = new Jugador();
        Controlador c = new Controlador();
        Vista v = new Vista(c);

        System.out.println("ej. Bolas de poder :\n(3,1) (3,26)" + "\n(23,1) (23,26)\n");
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Ingrese el x del objetivo : ");
        int xO = sc.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Ingrese el y del objetivo : ");
        int yO = sc.nextInt();
        pacman.setPosObjetivo(xO, yO);
        System.out.println("Pos obj : (" + pacman.getPosObjetivo().getX() + "," + pacman.getPosObjetivo().getY() + ")");
        int nPasos = pacman.getCaminoATomar().getLength();

        while (pacman.isPacmanVivo() && pacman.getCaminoATomar() != null) {
            if (pacman.getCaminoATomar() == null) {
                System.out.println("El camino a tomar es incorrecto.");
            } else
                for (int ronda = 1; ronda < nPasos + 1; ronda++) {
                    v.actualizar();

                    System.out.println("\nRonda = " + ronda);
                    System.out.println("Puntuacion = " + pacman.getPuntuacion());

                    System.out.println("-- Turno de Pac-Man --");
                    pacman.moverse();

                    c.setDataMap(pacman.getPuntajeMap());
                    int timer = sc.nextInt();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

.
    public class Controlador {

```
private int dataMap[][]=
    {
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,50,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,50,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,10,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,50,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,50,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1},
     {-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,-1,-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,10,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,10,-1},
     {-1,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,-1},
     {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    };

public void setDataMap(int[][] dataMap) {
    this.dataMap = dataMap;
}

public int[][] getDataMap(){
    return this.dataMap;
}
}
```

What im doing is changing the dataMap of the CONTROLLER when pacman eats and that's working fine, but the repainting its not.

Sorry for the messy code and my english.

Thank you all in advance!!!

Comment: Don't mix command line and graphics paradigms, they have different ways of working which make them some what incompatible at the best of times.  Instead, take a look at the [key bindings API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for away of getting input from the user

Comment: Doing `JLabel a = new JLabel();` is a bad idea, painting should only ever paint the current state of the UI, never modify it

Comment: I'd also suggest you have a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)